# Refresh jQuery datatable table

Tags: ajax, jquery, datatables

Been plenty of questions about this but I never found one that worked for me. I have a plain and simple HTML table whos body is being filled with rows from an AJAX call.
Then I want to update the table with DataTable plugin but it does not work.
I have a HTML table that looks like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
     <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my jQuery pageload

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
            "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": false },
              null, null, null, null
            ]
        });
});
```

And finally my on dropdownlist change function

```
$("#dropdownlist").on("change", function () {
        $("tbody").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("ActionHere", "Controller")",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        $("tbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>");
                    });
                }
            })
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable(); // Nothing happens
        var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({ // Cannot initialize it again error
                "aoColumns": [
                  { "bSortable": false },
                  null, null, null, null
                ]
            });
        });
```

The append and so on has been modified to shorten it down, etc so do not focus too much on it.

Basically the question is how to update the table, I can do my AJAX and add new data to the table fine, but the datatable plugin does not update with it.
I've tried other things like

> .fnDraw(false);

But it does nothing
While I get an JSON error from

> fnReloadAjax()

Any clues on just how to refresh the table?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this

Initially you initialized the table so first clear that table

`$('#myTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();`

Then initialize again after ajax success

```
$('#myTable').dataTable();
```

Like this

```
$("#dropdownlist").on("change", function () {
        $("tbody").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("ActionHere", "Controller")",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        $("tbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>");
                    });
                }
            })
       $('#myTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
       $('#myTable').dataTable({ // Cannot initialize it again error
                "aoColumns": [
                  { "bSortable": false },
                  null, null, null, null
                ]
            });
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gVtj8/)

Comment: Got it to work after a while, my AJAX was a bit too heavy for it and there seems to be a lot of browser incompabilities but it works fine for now.

Comment: add this piece of setting in there: "bDeferRender": true

Comment: please check this for latest version : https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3. Use $('#myTable').DataTable().destroy() instead of ..fnDestroy()

Answer (score 3):

I Know this is an old post, but I've just investigated about the problem and I find the easiest way to solve it in DataTable man pages: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29
All you need to call table.ajax.reload();

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Have "destroy: true," in your datatable and when you want to reload, use table.ajax.reload();

Answer (score 2):

```
var table =  $('#product_table').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    responsive: true,
    "ajax": {
        url: get_base_url + "product_table", // json datasource
        type: "post", // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
        error: function () {
            $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
});

//call this funtion 
$(document).on('click', '#view_product', function () {
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done something that relates to this... Below is a sample javascript with what you need. There is a demo on this here: http://codersfolder.com/2016/07/crud-with-php-mysqli-bootstrap-datatables-jquery-plugin/

```
//global the manage member table 
var manageMemberTable;

function updateMember(id = null) {
    if(id) {
        // click on update button
        $("#updatebutton").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'webdesign_action/update.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {member_id : id},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response) {
                    if(response.success == true) {                      
                        $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                              '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                            '</div>');

                        // refresh the table

                        manageMemberTable.ajax.reload();

                        // close the modal
                        $("#updateModal").modal('hide');

                    } else {
                        $(".removeMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                              '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                            '</div>');

                        // refresh the table                        
                        manageMemberTable.ajax.reload();

                        // close the modal
                        $("#updateModal").modal('hide');
                    }
                }
            });
        }); // click remove btn
    } else {
        alert('Error: Refresh the page again');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From version 1.10.0 onwards you can use [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) api.

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.ajax.reload();
```

> Keep in mind to use `$('#myTable').DataTable()` and not
>   `$('#myTable').dataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

Put cache=false in your ajax call e.g.

```
$("#dropdownlist").on("change", function () {
        $("tbody").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false, // THIS IS THE LINE YOU SHOULD ADD
                url: "@Url.Action("ActionHere", "Controller")",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        $("tbody").append("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>");
                    });
                }
            })
       $('#myTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
       $('#myTable').dataTable({ // Cannot initialize it again error
                "aoColumns": [
                  { "bSortable": false },
                  null, null, null, null
                ]
            });
        });
```