# Updating Datatable with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am working with Datatables with AJAX where I generate a table when the page loads. This first part of my code works fine. Based on user input I then want to update the table with new data.

Right now when I call the function updateTable() it returns the proper JSON for what I send it but I can't figure out how to actually update the table. The 'success' part is wrong but I am not sure what to do I have tried lots of api functions but nothing seems to work. Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {



var valve = "1-8000AL" //$("#valveSelect").val();
var tab = "1"
$('#dataTable').dataTable( {
    "scrollY":  "400px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,

    "ajax": {"url": "ajax/update.php","data": {"valve" : valve, "tab" : tab}},
    "dom": '<"top">rts<"bottom"filp><"clear">'
}); 



function updateTable(){

    var valve = $("#valveSelect").val();
    var tab = "2" 
    $('h3').text(tab);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/update.php",
        data:{"valve" : valve, "tab" : tab},
        success: $('#dataTable').dataTable().draw()
    });

};
```

});

Comment: success should look something like `success: function(data){ ... }` where `data` is the json passed in.

Comment: did you check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141432/refresh-jquery-datatable-table

Comment: @Ballbin could you be more specific? My ajax url 'update.php' echos the JSON data but I don't know how to grab it. When the page initializes in the first section of code I don't do anything it just fills the table.

Comment: @Sherif I looked at that, it is using the older version of Datatables. I could try and destroy and rebuild the table using the new syntax but it doesn't seem like the right way. I am still learning but it SEEMS like there should be a way to update the table without destroying and rebuilding it every time.

Comment: @gback The `data` argument passed into the function will be the data that was passed back from `update.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `.DataTable` to construct your datatable, not `.dataTable`.
`.DataTable` is the new style from datatables 1.10. `.DataTable` returns a DataTables api instance, while `.dataTable` returns a jquery object.

The solution I use is to construct the query string manually (using $.param()), and then use the datatables API to reload the data from the new location.

```
function updateTable(){
    var valve = $("#valveSelect").val();
    var tab = "2"
    var query_string = $.param({"valve" : valve, "tab" : tab})
    var ajax_source = "ajax/update.php?" + query_string
    var table = $("#dataTable").DataTable(); // get api instance
    // load data using api
    table.ajax.url(ajax_source).load();
};
```

Comment: This is close! Quick thing: $.params should be $.param I think. The bigger issue I am having is that this is adding valve and tab to the query string twice. The first is the new values I selected but then the default values are added on as well, not sure why. EX: ajax/update.php?valve=1-8100&tab=2&valve=1-8000AL&tab=1&_=1402334290466

Comment: Do you have two elements with an id '#valveSelect' on your page? If yes, either cleanup your DOM id creation, or use something like $("#valveSelect").last().val() or $("#valveSelect").first().val() instead. This is a separate issue from your original question.

Comment: I just tried commenting out the ajax request from the datatable initialization and replaced it with a call to the updateTable function to load the default data that way and everything works. The issue had something to do with that first ajax statement. Not really sure why.