# Sorting jQuery datatable and ignoring empty entries, with Client-side data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

So the question is, how to sort a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) and ignoring the empty cells (or cells with just "-"). More accurate I want the empty cells to be at the bottom (for desc and asc). This Question has already been answered here [Sorting (alphabetical order) to ignore empty cells : dataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944854/sorting-alphabetical-order-to-ignore-empty-cells-datatables). But the solution doesn't work for me, because i have a [Client-side data source](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html) and the new sorting takes forever.

Update:
By adding this code, if you click on the first entry (ID), the whole sorting takes far too long.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
            return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
            return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
       }
    } );


var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       {type: 'non-empty-string', targets: 0} // define 'name' column as non-empty-string type
    ]
});`
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/36zxs9f6/2/

Comment: Client-side data source works the same way. Please provide your code so we could check it.

Comment: Okay i added an example.