# How to sort the datetime field in datatable plugin in PHP?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I'm used to sort the date and time field in datatable plugin.but it not working it sort in the order of 9,8,7,...12,11,10. If I'm use some custom code for sorting I works but it is not sorting for some data's

Custom code:

HTML and JS

```
<td><?=  $date ? $date : '-' ?></td>

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-pre'] = function(a) {
var a = a.split('m')[0];
a=a+'m';
a = a.slice(0, -2) + ' ' + a.slice(-2);
var date = Date.parse(a);
return typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1;
}
```

datatable:

```
$('#id').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "aoColumns": [
       { "bSortable": false },  
       { sType: 'uk_date' },
       null
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'desc']],
});
```

Comment: Why does this have the php tag ?

Comment: For backend i'm using php

Comment: is it possible to add fiddle or running sample with only datepicker along with similar error/issue?

Comment: Hi,@Developerrr thanks for the comment. I edited the question now it simple and i found the issue.if date field is empty then it occurs error in sorting.can it possible to bring the empty fields in end of the table while sorting.

Comment: @Developerrr and i found some solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944854/sorting-alphabetical-order-to-ignore-empty-cells-datatables but it make hard to implement in this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Great.. Glad to hear! Happy coding 

Comment: Thank :) for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer thanks you for all for your comments

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-pre'] = function(a) {
var a = a.split('m')[0];
if(a == '-'){
        return -1;
    }
a=a+'m';
a = a.slice(0, -2) + ' ' + a.slice(-2);
var date = Date.parse(a);
return typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1;
}
```