# How to use aaData to refresh datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934144/how-to-reload-refresh-jquery-datatable) solution to refresh a datatable. I obtained the newly refreshed JSON data through an ajax call. But I'm not sure how to use it. In particular, how do convert it to be compatible with the datatable **aaData** attribute?

```
success:
  function (json){

    var data = json;
    table =$(#mytable).dataTable();
    oSettings = table.fnSettings();
    table.fnClearTable(this);

    $.each(json, function (i, item) {
      table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json[i]);
    });


    oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
    table.fnDraw();
  }
```

For now, I'm trying to directly use json[i] and that is giving me errors in datatable. Also , the returned data is an array of json objects.

Comment: Refresh the datatable using ajax [Refer to this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141432/refresh-jquery-datatable-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh jQuery datatable table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141432/refresh-jquery-datatable-table)

Answer (score 0):

i have different method from you but try it, it will always works for me with datatable

when you receive the success then execute this

```
$("#example1").load(location.href + " #example1"); //give your table id
```

this will only refresh the table.